# What regex matches this type of timestamp

Tags: python, regex, timestamp

I've got a log file with the following time stamp format:

```
May 02 13:27:15.722996
```

What regex should I use to match that? i.e. from a two hundred character line I just want to return this particular string - it's always at the beginning of the line...

Comment: Will be running this in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
/^[A-Z][a-z]{2,} \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{6}$/
```

Comment: And don't forget to set the option that `^` and `$` should match at the start/end of lines.

Comment: In Python, that would be `myre = re.compile(r"^[A-Z][a-z]{2,} \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{6}$", re.M)`

Answer (score 3):

A simple pattern can be:

```
^\w+\s\d\d\s\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d+
```

Not much to it, really. You can replace `\d` with `[0-9]`, or maybe compact it a little, but it's pretty straightforward. You may also want to make some of the digits optional, in case you don't have leading zeros (`May 3 1:2:3.34`, for example):

```
^\w+\s\d\d?\s\d\d?:\d\d?:\d\d?\.\d+
```